# How can I use SCENE_CREATE_FUNC() when extending CCScene in cocos2d-x?

Tags: cocos2d-x

I have read this question carefully ---- [Using CREATE_FUNC in Cocos2dx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22151939/using-create-func-in-cocos2dx). Today I found some code used `SCENE_CREATE_FUNC()` , but when I tried to use it in my Custom CCScene .There is always an error.

Comment: ... what error exactly?

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Visual Studio didn't know the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that new version of cocos2d-x have remove the `SCENE_CREATE_FUNC` function. It suggests to use `CREATE_FUNC` .

reference:

1. http://www.cocos2d-x.org/issues/1442
2. https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/pull/1246

Comment: You can use `CREATE_FUNC` macro to create auto released objects of classes inherited by CCObject.